# (char); What is the purpose of this code?

Tags: java, class, methods, char

and thank you for your time,

For the following code (a method for a class), I am not sure what the (char) is supposed to do. B arg 1 has a `char` and at the end I also get a char.

So, does the `(char)` work like a cast or? If it's more commonly used I would like to learn more about it, so I would appreciate if you could tell me where to look specifically.

```
static B calculer(B arg1, int arg2) {
    arg1.b = (char)(arg1.b + arg2);
}
```

Comment: (char) could mean that (arg1.b + arg2) is casted to a char inbuilt type.

Comment: While we are at it, this is why people spend weeks of their lifes to write lnaguage specifications. And the Java Language Specification explains all this in full detail. But it seems that people nowadays call themselves programmers without even knowing that such specifications exists and can be downloaded for free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It casts `(arg1.b + arg2)` to a `char`.

When there are multiple data types that can be interpreted, you cast it to the one you want.

For instance, if I was to try to display the number 97 as a `char` instead of just the `int` `97` that it would normally be interpreted as, I would cast is as such:

```
System.out.println( (char)97 ); // will display 'a', instead of 97
```

I could display `a` as `97` by casting it to an `int` as well.

In your case, it will interpret `(arg1.b + arg2)` as a `char`, instead of what it normally would be.

**Example**:

I wrote this code (where `'a'` represents `arg1.b` and `5` represents `arg2`:

```
char x = (char)('a' + 5);
System.out.println(x); // displayed 'f'
```

It displayed `'f'` because it added `'a'` and `5` together, which it interpreted as 97 + 5 (97 is the [ASCHII](http://www.asciitable.com/) value of `'a'`, or the `int` value of it essentially), and then would be left with `(char)(102)` which would then be interpreted as `'f'` (the `char` value of `102`).

Answer (score 2):

Java characters are numbers behind the scenes where the character actually holds the Unicode codepoint. The Java char is an unsigned 16-bit number (UTF-16). So you can treat them like numbers in many ways. What this does is add `arg2` to the Unicode value of `arg.b`.

For example if `arg.b` is `'a'` (codepoint is decimal 97) and `arg1` is `10` on return of the method `arg.b` will now be `'k'` (codepoint is decimal 107).

Because Java promotes data types during numerical operations, after adding an int to a char the result of the expression is an int not a char. The char gets promoted to an int. So the cast is needed to turn the result back in to a char for the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

it's called casting. What casting does is transforms some other data type (like int) into a character. I think this is Java code? So you want to learn a little bit more about java characters and the way it handles this kind of situations.